# Cannot restore database as file is being used by another process

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-restore

I have developed this application for a store owner.I want to allow the owner to backup and restore database by using the application.the backup runs fine but the restore is causing an exception which says that - Operating system error 32( the process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process).Restore database is terminated abnormally.

```
         using(var conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
         {
                 using(SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
                  {
                         string datadirectory = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory,@"Data");
                         string query = @"RESTORE DATABASE""{0}""FROM DISK= '{1}' WITH REPLACE";
                         string query = String.Format(query,backupfile,datadirectory + "\\Database.mdf");  
                         conn.Open();
                         SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query,conn);
                         command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                  }
         }
```

How can I solve this issue ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Trying making it offline and then restore.This way all connected users will disconnected. Before you do, Please inform all your stakeholder that database will be down for a while.

Answer (score 0):

You have to dispose of every SQLiteConnection, SQLiteCommand and SQLiteDataReader once you are done using it. The second command that you create isn't correctly being disposed off.

That aside, your code sample doesn't really make sense. You create a command that is never used. Then you create a second command that isn't properly disposed off.

Answer (score 0):

Is it the restore-file that is blocking? Or is the database itself still running?

If it is the database that is being used, you can set the database in single-user-mode. Another option is taking the database temporarily offline and bring it online again. That should close all existing connections.  Tip; with SSMS you can turn almost every command into an SQL script like the button to brink a database offline. Click on 'Script' and you get something like 'USE MASTER GO ALTER DATABASE [AdventureWorks] SET  OFFLINE GO'.

Answer (score -1):

wait, this is good news. it looks like the application is running, the db is online and live, so why do want to restore? backups are something you do daily/hourly... but restores you ONLY do if something goes wrong. of course you got an error. the db is live and sql service is using the files and it's good it didn't let you restore or else you would have lost a lot of data.

if all you want is to test the restore, then you need to shut down the sql service first.BUT, make sure you take a backup just before that so you restore the latest.